# Out of memory exception in my code

Tags: java, sql, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory

I am running a code for long hours as part of a stress test on an Oracle db and using java version "1.4.2". In a nutshell, what I am doing is :

```
while(true)
{
    Allocating some memory as a blob
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    stmt = fConnection.prepareStatement(query); // [compiling an insert query which uses the above blob]
    stmt.execute();  // I insert this blob-row in the database. 
stmt.close();

}
```

Now I want to run this test for 8-10 hrs. However apparently after inserting about 15million records I hit the **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**

I am running this with  -Xms512m -Xmx2g . I tried using higher values but I dont seem to have that much hardware neither do I think it is req:

```
    java -Xms512m -Xmx4g -jar XX.jar
    Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
    The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
    java -Xms2g -Xmx3g -jar XX.jar
    Error occurred during initialization of VM
    Could not reserve enough space for object heap
    Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I run this as a multithreaded program. So arnd 10 threads are doing the inserts.

Is there any way I can get around this program in possibly no-hack manner. I mean what if I decide to run this for 15-20 hrs instead of 8-10 hrs.

EDIT:
added stmt.close since I am using that in my code already. 
some changes based on comments

Thanks

P.S: sorry cant post the code bec of NDA

Comment: Have you checked your system hard limit for processes? You can check them with limit or ulimit depending on the shell you are using.

Comment: "You think"? Get out your profiler and see what's actually going on.

Comment: the exception points to the line of code where I do byte[] data = new byte[1000];

Comment: Which DB and JDBC driver? Post more code - are you closing your statements, reusing them, or leaving them to fester? Have you enabled heap dumps on OOM, and did they give you any clues?

Comment: It doesn't matter what line the exception happens on. The thing about out-of-memory errors is that the allocation that crashes is essentially random, and most likely completely unrelated to the thing that's actually leaking memory. Get out some debugging tools and look at the heap, watch what gets allocated, what gets collected, and what gets left behind.

Comment: You should profile your code, otherwise it would be hard to understand what is leaking..

Comment: thnx guys I ll try tp profile my code. Any tool you recommend I , had tried using jrat but didnt find them very straightforward to use. I am using eclipse.

Comment: Maybe you can post a more complete sample of your code ? You might also try running the code in a standalone class with just a main in it and if needed a couple of static methods.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, I think you are barking up the wrong tree:

- The JVM / GC *will* manage to deallocate unreachable objects, no matter how fast you allocate them.  If you are running the classic non-concurrent GC, then JVM will simply stop doing other things until the GC has deallocated memory.  If you configured your JVM to use a concurrent GC, it will try to run the GC and normal worker threads at the same time ... and revert to "stop everything and collect" behaviour if it cannot keep up.
- If you are running out of memory, it is because something in your application (or the libraries / drivers it is using) is leaking memory.  In other words, something is causing objects to remain reachable, even though your application doesn't need them any more.

As comments have pointed out, you need to address this problem methodically using a memory profiler / heap dump.  Randomly changing things or blaming it on the GC is highly unlikely to fix the problem.

(When you say *"... I did use stmt.close() all the time"*, I assume that this means that your code looks something like this:

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = ... 
    try {
        stmt.execute();
        // ...
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
    }
```

If you don't put the `close` call in a `finally` then it is possible that you are NOT calling `close` every time.  In particular, if some exception gets thrown during the `execute` call or between it and the `close` call, then it is possible that `close` will not get called ... and that will result in a leak.)

Comment: I meant that it gets closed in each iteration of the while loop; this way I give away memory allocated to a stmt after every iteration and dont wait for billion allocations to happen before I close in finally. However bec of having prep stmt in the loop I am compiling the stmt each iteration as well which I think is inefficient and I will change that. However I dont see any other exception being thrown. I see your point though and have added a finally block as well.

Comment: @p1 - IMO, it is "best practice" to release resource handles in a `finally` block, even if you cannot imagine any way that an exception might be thrown.  (And, of course, there is a good chance that your memory leak or leaks are somewhere else ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add

```
stmt.close();
```

so the memory allocated to the preparedStatement will be freed.

Comment: Hey thnx, I already have stmt.close(); However I prepare the statement just once and use it millions of time .. so I think memory is allocated to statement only once.

Comment: @p1: you don't just prepare the statement once according to the code you posted...

Comment: yeah , thats the change I did later. However I did use stmt.close() all the time

Comment: The statement might allocate blocks of memory during execute() method. And depending on how the database driver written, it could remove the reference to the memory (so the memory could be Garbage Collec ted) when close() on the statement object is called or it could remove the reference to the memory when close() on the connection object is called..

Answer (score 1):

If there is a leak, either in your code or a library, the Memory Analyser (MAT) is a free Eclipse based app for delving into Java memory dump files. Instructions include how to get it to drop the dump file for you.
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: I tried using it as per the link but dont see (.hprof) file generated anywhere. I used the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in config arguments as mentioned. Any suggestions ?

Comment: there are a few ways to get the hprof file. My preference is the setting you have used, the file should be in the 'current working directory for the application', which isn't always easy to define :) Have you tried running a search on the file system?

Answer (score 1):

This execution causes from OracleConnection NativeMemory. For NIO operations oracle jdbc guys decided to use native part of the memory. Most probably after executing this query too frequently makes your application to dump. To get rid of this, you can increase cache size of jdbc or restart your application in time intervals

Answer (score 0):

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx3 -jar XX.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

Try

```
java -Xms2g -Xmx3g -jar XX.jar
```

How much memory do you have on your box?  Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?

Comment: tried that and updated it in question. top shows I am using Mem:   3891380k total Swap:  1048568k total

Comment: I didn't ask how much memory is in use, I asked how much memory is available on the system?  And which JVM are you running?  Try java -version on the command line and put the output in your question.

Comment: I don't think this is his problem.  His application is simply inserting lots of records as a stress test.  This should not require an ever increasing amount of memory ... and giving it more memory simply puts off the problem.

Comment: I agree with Stephen.. giving more memory wont scale if I run my prog for long hours... the TOP command also gives you total memory, which I have pasted,apart from the mem in use. Updated the java version in the question

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** seems that it may be a known Oracle driver issue:
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=10218

---

Just a longshot, I know you are doing plain JDBC here, but if you hapen have any enhancers (AspectJ, Hibernate, JPA) there is a (slight) chance of a Perm gen leak, set `-XX:MaxPermGen=256m` just to be on the safe side

Also jvisualvm memory profiler and jprofiler (you can use the trial) will pin point it faster