# help with Eclipse Memory Analyzer [MAT]

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-leaks, eclipse-plugin

I tried using MAT as per [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html) link but dont see (.hprof) file generated anywhere after running the code. I used the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError in config arguments as mentioned.

Any specific permissions etc I need to get it working ?

P.S:
For context on why I am using the mem analyzer please check the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425106/out-of-memory-exception-in-my-code):

Comment: Have you checked the `JAVA_HOME/bin` dir too?

Comment: Maybe a refresh in the Eclipse is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an older version of MAT installed. I installed the newer one and it worked fine in eclipse. thought the older version shld also have worked imo

Answer (score 0):

No special permissions are needed.

I've created a simple class:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        String a = "3";
        while (true) {
            a = a + a;
        }
    }
}
```

Then compiled it:

```
javac A.java
```

And then ran it:

```
java -Xmx1m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError A
```

and got the dump file (.hprof).

How does it differ from your procedure?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to get a dump from a running process without terminating it .. irrespective of weather an out of memory is thrown or not. the newer version allows to do that using eclipse